# git strategy on merging/rebasing feature that was abandoned but is being revived

Tags: git, workflows

Say we have this situation:

```
* master
| 
* a
| 
* b
      ... a lot has happened
*
      ... a lot has happened
* z
|
|  * aa (want to rebase onto master or merge into master but having too many conflicts)
|  |
|  * bb
....
|  |
|  * yy
|  |
|  * zz
| / 
* parent
```

`parent` to `master` has extensive code refactoring done
`parent` to `aa` has extensive code refactoring done, but different refactoring

I need to merge `aa` into `master`.  Or rebase `aa` onto `master`, in order to bring `aa` back into business.

I tried doing both, and both seem painful.  I have about 13 rebase fixes to do if I go the rebase route. and as I go step by step, something breaks because of the different refactoring done on either branches.  So I in a way re-refactor and amend things when I rebase.

When I do the merge, at least I know what I need to fix right away, as all conflicts are shown immediately.  Except the `aa` feature was done so long ago I can't readily wrap my head around all the conflicts.  I could say that rebase, at least, gives it to me step by step.

But both seem quite difficult and I know that git has an excellent reputation when it comes to merges.  So maybe I am struggling for naught?  Is there a better way?

My goal is to bring `parent` to `aa` path back into my master.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

While git is great, merging/rebasing an out-of-date feature branch is always going to be a painful experience. There is no magic bullet (of which I am aware) that will make this headache go away.

In my experience, I prefer rebasing over merging in these situations for the reasons you mentioned: you can resolve the errors in each commit one at a time, and ensure that everything builds and your tests pass before moving on to the next commit.

In extremely difficult rebases, I have actually reimplemented the feature using the commit diffs from the feature branch as a guide. As crazy as it might sound, it can actually be much quicker to quickly add a few classes and tests to the current codebase than to resolve conflicts for a feature that was a designed for a very different and out-of-date codebase.

Comment: Where I work we've also had to reimplement feature branches because they'd gotten neglected and the head had diverged so much from them. It's not always as crazy as it might sound.

Comment: that works for me, thanks.  I'll try the rebase first, and if that fails.... reimplement..

Comment: I should note that you can also mention use of `git mergetool`.  And there is also a git option that stays with git which tells git to save previously resolved conflicts which it can resolve auto-magically should they show up again.  with mergetool my `rebase` went pretty great!  I barely had to do anything!  And what git could not resolve, kdiff3 automagically did in a couple of cases